# How do I filter DataRows on a list of values?

Tags: c#, list, linq, datarow

I have a collection of DataRow's that have a column TransactionID - I'm trying to filter out the DataRow's that don't have a matching value in a list of TransactionID's

```
List<int?> IDs = _sqlResultsRaw.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => x.Field<int?>("TransactionID")).ToList();
List<int?> pIDs = _sqlResultsRaw.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => x.Field<int?>("ParentTransactionID")).ToList();

List<int?> IDsToKeep = IDs.Except(pIDs).ToList();
```

I want to create a collection of DataRows that have a matching value from IDsToKeep. If the TransactionID isn't in IDsToKeep, I want to remove it

Answer (score 0):

```
        EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> val = _sqlResultsRaw.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => IDsToKeep.Contains((int)x["TransactionID"]));
```

Comment: You may want to consider having `IdsToKeep` be a `HashSet` for lookup performance (use `ToHashSet` instead of `ToList` with `var`). Some reason you didn't use `Field<int?>("TransactionID")`?